# React-route useHistory doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend, react-router-v4

Hi I'm doing a project with react and nodejs, I'm using window.location.href to redirect to another page if person successfully logged in and wanted to use useHistory to redirect to another page without updating, but it doesn't work, it gives me the following error

```
Error

Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See -invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I use it as is as it is in the react-route documentation (I think)

Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './main.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect, useHistory,
  useLocation, browserHistory, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import Register from './components/ComponentRegister'
import Login from './components/ContainerLogin'
import ChatPrincipal from './Chat/ChatPrincipal'

class App extends Component {


  
  state = {
    username: '',
    status: Number,
    message: '',
    messageError: ''
  }

componentDidMount(){
// localStorage.setItem('sesion', '')
}

  userLogin = (username, password) =>{
    const url = 'http://192.168.1.7:3000/api/login'


     fetch('/api/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
    })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data =>{
      if(data.status === 200){
        console.log('hola')
        this.setState({
          status: data.status,
          message: data.message,
          username: username
        })
        this.userSearch()
      }
    }) 
    
  }


  login = (username, password) =>{
    let history = useHistory() <====================== Error
    fetch('/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
    })
    .then(r => r.json())

    .then(data =>{
      console.log(data.status)
      if(data.status === 200){
        console.log('si')
         this.setState({
          status: data.status,
          message: data.message,
          username: username
        })
        this.userSearch() 
      }else{
        this.setState({
          messageError: data.message,
          status: data.status
        })
        console.log('Error')
        const error = document.getElementById('Error')

      }
    }) 
 
    
  }
  

  userSearch = () =>{
    console.log('hola')
    const sesionGet = localStorage.getItem('sesion')
    const url = `/api/userSearch/${this.state.username}`
    fetch(url)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.user._id)
        localStorage.setItem('sesion', data.user._id)
    })
    .then(console.log)
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = "/"
    }, 1000);
  }

  userRegister = (username, password) =>{
    const url = ''
    
    fetch('/api/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
    })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => {
      if(data.status === 200){
        console.log(data.status, 'jeje')
        this.setState({
          status: data.status
        })
      }else{
        this.setState({
          status: data.status,
          messageError: data.message

        })
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (

      
     <Router>
      <div>
          <Switch>

          <Route exact path="/">
          <ChatPrincipal/>
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/init/login">
          <Login status={this.state.status} error={this.state.messageError} login={this.login}/>
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/init/register">
          <Register status={this.state.status} register={this.userRegister}/>
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/init/chat">
          
          </Route >
          </Switch>

        
      </div>
      </Router> 
    )
  }
}


export default App;
)
```

And just invoking the useHistory function immediately gives me the above error causing me to not be able to use your function to redirect to pages

```
history.push('/')
```

Comment: Are you using the hook within a component? From your question code, it appears you are just importing it and using directly in the body of a file?

Comment: can you share where you define the routing context

Comment: can you share the component code

Comment: Sure, I already edit the question

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when I was using `ContextProvider` and `BrowserRouter`, I had a composition like this:

```html
ReactDOM.render(
  <ContextProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ContextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`ContextProvider` wasn't wrapped by `BrowserRouter`. I solved this by wrapping `ContextProvider` with `BrowserRouter`, like this:

```html
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ContextProvider>
      <App />
    </ContextProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use hooks inside a component. Also push method takes object with pathname property as an argument: `history.push({pathname: '/'})`. Another rules of using hooks on official website: [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)